# Use old database in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I just set up rails app from my old pc to new one. Everything is working fine. But I don't have any data in the database. But I have my previous database from my old pc. How can I use this old database so that I get all the previous data? I am using mysql database, rails 3.2 and ruby.  1.9.3. So basically I need to import data from old database to new one. Or can I just change the new sql file with the new one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysqldump` as following to get the old DB from the old PC:

```
backup: # mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```

Then take that `.sql` resulting file to the new PC, and do the following:

```
restore:# mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
```

Also make sure that `config/database.yml` in your Rails application is using the correct database name and password.